# Flickering and artifacts when capturing screen using ffmpeg and x11grab

Tags: x11, ffmpeg, manjaro, plasma5

I'm using the following command to capture my screen: `ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0.0+1920,0 -c:v libx264 artifact-test.mkv`

The resulting video contains flickering artifacts that look a bit like portions of the background image come to the foreground for a few milliseconds: https://i.imgur.com/l9PDXD6.mp4

The video was recorded directly after a reboot with only a texteditor (Kate) running. The artifacts also occur when recording the screen without a running application but are harder to notice.

I'm using Manjaro Linux with:

- KDE Plasma Version: 5.14.3
- Qt Version: 5.11.2
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.52.0
- Kernel Version: 4.14.81-1-MANJARO
- OS Type: 64-bit

And the following ffmpeg installation:

`ffmpeg version n4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20180831
configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100`

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Nvidia GPU, try disabling the OpenGL option "Allow Flipping" it causes this, at least for me it did

Comment: After scouring countless forums, this tiny detail finally fixed it for me. +1

Comment: how do i disable this?

Comment: @chovy smewhere in "Nvidia X Server Settings", sorry cant say exact location, because i didnt use an nvidia gpu in an long time, and the software for an laptop dosnt have this option (cannot find it)